# determine analytic function $f$ if $|f|=(x^2+y^2)e^x$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I'm self-studying complex analysis. Could someone please help me get this problem started?

I know an analytic function will satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, but I only know the modulus of the function. I have no idea how to proceed

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are real variables, that quantity is always positive. Thus $|f| = f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x^2 + y^2 = |z^2|$, and $e^{x} = |e^z|$, where $z = x+iy$.

Comment: okay I checked your statements. Then It's $f(z)=e^z\cdot z^2$ and I can use the Cauchy Riemann equations to verify it's analytic. Thanks!